# Dockerfile build error using Powershell for windows 10 and sdk 3.0

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, sdk3.0

If I build my docker file using cmd

> docker build -t myimage -f Dockerfile. 
>   getting this error.
>   unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in the Dockerfile path: CreateFile F:\Docker\demo\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: `docker build  -f Dockerfile.txt -t myimage .`

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile should contain

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY app/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.0/publish/ app/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/myapp.dll"]

dockerfile extension has to be given as shown while running from powershell

> docker build -t myimage -f Dockerfile.txt .

Comment: please do not add more info as an answer , you can edit the question with this info